# In a Postgresql database where a seller has many products and products have many sellers, where should price(s) get stored?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

Using django and python, I am building a web app that tracks prices. The user is a manufacturer and will want reports. Each of their products has a recommended price. Each product could have more than one seller, and each seller could have more than one product. My question is, where do I store the prices, especially the seller's price? Right now I have my database schema so the product table stores the recommended price and the seller's price, and that means one single product is repeated a lot of times. Is there a better way to do this?

[image: DB Schema]

Per the recommendations below this is the correct db schema:
[image]

Comment: Since it’s a many-to-many relationship then there’s a link table between the tables which can house the variable information, like price

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, so does that mean this schema is correct and the magic of the database makes the link table?

Comment: You may want an additional model called `SellerProduct` which would have attributes `seller, product, and price`.

Comment: Totally off topic, but if this is a new database, do yourself a huge favor and use `bigint` instead of `integer` as the data type of any id field. It uses more hard drive space, but you’ll thank yourself in the long run because you’d inevitably run out of ids when using `integer`. And when that time comes, you’d otherwise have to update over 2 billion rows (times how many tables you have) to convert your data types while the system is running (a process that can take hours depending on how many rows/tables there are). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I've updated my question to show the recommended db schema. @Nate, thank you for the comment, I will use that in the implementation. The db schema tool I use doesn't have bigint as an option or the new schema would reflect your recommendation!

Comment: You’re welcome! Here’s a blog post from the creator of Basecamp (a popular project management tool). He comments about how they were stuck in read only mode for hours while they upgraded from integer to bigint in November because they did not realize they had integer as the data type until it stopped being able to insert into the table. It was not fun for them. https://m.signalvnoise.com/update-on-basecamp-3-being-stuck-in-read-only-as-of-nov-8-9-22am-cst-c41df1a58352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a case of many-to-many then your structure would use a link table. You’ll have tables `seller`, `product` and `link_seller_product`. The last table has a link to the `seller` table via id as well as the `product` table via id. This table therefore can also have any information that is dependent on the seller and the product and is not fixed for either. So price-per-product-per-seller goes there.

So add the additional link table with columns `sellerid`, `productid` and `price` and you’ll have only single rows in sellers and products but each seller can have their own price for the product.

Comment: This is for sure the answer. Though I would take a suggestion from Ruby On Rails and try to make that join table’s name meaningful. Is there some more useful name for the table that you can think of for your industry? Perhaps “ProductContract” or something? I could see you also storing a price_negotiated_at column of when this seller product price was set, for example. That’s why I’d try to think of it as a proper model with a good name.

Answer (score 1):

You're not adequately representing the one-to-many relationship between products and sellers.  Your product table has the seller_id and the seller_price, but if one product is sold by many sellers, it cannot.

Instead of duplicating product entries so the same product can have multiple sellers, what you need is a table between products and sellers.

```
CREATE TABLE seller_products (
   seller_id integer,
   product_id integer,
   price decimal 
);
```

I'll leave the indexes foreign keys etc to you.  Seller ID and product ID might be a unique combination ( historical data is best removed from active datasets for performance longevity ) , but of course any given product will be listed once for each seller that sells it and any given seller will be listed once per product it sells ( along with its unique price).

Then you can join the table back to products to get the data you currently store denormalized in the `products` table directly :

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN seller_products ON ( seller_products.product_id = products.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Data Warehouse question.

I would recommend putting prices on a Fact as measures and having only attributes on the Dimensions.

Dimensions:

- Product
- Seller
- Manufacturer

Fact (Columns):

- List item
- Seller Price
- List item
- MRSP
- Product ID
- Seller ID
- Manufacturer ID
- Timestamp

Comment: I personally would not characterize this as a data warehouse question.  But, I suppose you could argue that sellers' prices is not part of this particular data set.  As the question is written I don't really see why denormalizing into a data warehouse is a correct approach, but for history, it would be great.

Comment: OP asked about duplicating a single Product multiple times.  A Data Warehouse approach is needed to solve that and solve it and to solve it at scale.  A mistake about which columns go on which tables is only made worse as the data grows.